# Regex to match a string NOT surrounded by brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have to parse a text where *with* is a key word if it is not surrounded by square brackets. I have to match the keyword *with*. Also, there must be word boundaries on both side of *with*.

Here are some examples where *with* is NOT a keyword:

- [with]
- [ with ]
- [sometext with sometext]
- [sometext with]
- [with sometext]

Here are some examples where *with* IS keyword

- with
- ] with
- hello with
- hello with world
- hello [ world] with hello
- hello [ world] with hello [world]

Anyone to help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can look for the word `with` and see that the closest bracket to its left side is not an opening bracket, and that the closest bracket to its right side is not a closing bracket:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(?<!     # Assert that we can't match this before the current position:
     \[        #  An opening bracket
     [^[\]]*   #  followed by any other characters except brackets.
    )          # End of lookbehind.
    \bwith\b   # Match ""with"".
    (?!        # Assert that we can't match this after the current position:
     [^[\]]*   #  Any text except brackets
     \]        #  followed by a closing bracket.
    )          # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    // matched text: matchResults.Value
    // match start: matchResults.Index
    // match length: matchResults.Length
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

The lookaround expressions don't stop at line breaks; if you want each line to be evaluated separately, use `[^[\]\r\n]*` instead of  `[^[\]]*`.

Comment: @Tim: Your solution really helped me a lot. Now I have similar problem, only that, the brackets will be replaced by quotes. I mean `"sometext with sometext"` is NOT a keyword. I tried to replace brackets with quotes but it does not work. I am really too bad in Regex, I need your help again. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mohaimin, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111749/replace-whitespace-outside-quotes-using-regular-expression/6112179#6112179) which is about a very similar problem; just replace the `[\ ]` part in the regex with `\bwith\b`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, that was perfect. I needed just a little modification because I had to merge the quote finding regex with the one you gave above. It worked just fine :D

Answer (score 3):

Nice question.  I think it'll be easier to find the matches where your `[with]` pattern applies, and then inverse the result.

You need to match `[`, not followed by `]`, followed by `with` (and then the corresponding pattern for closed square bracket)

Matching the `[` and the `with` are easy.

```
\[with
```

add a lookahead to exclude `]`, and also allow any number of other characters (`.*`)

```
\[(?!]).*with
```

then the corresponding closed square bracket, i.e. the reverse with a lookbehind.

```
\[(?!]).*with.*\](?<1[)
```

a bit more tweaking

```
\[(?!(.*\].*with)).*with.*\](?<!(with.*\[.*))
```

and now if you inverse this, you should have your desired result. (i.e. when this returns 'true', your pattern matches and want to exclude those results).

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is to preemptively match balanced pairs of brackets and their contents to get them out of the way as you search for the keyword.  Here's an example:

```
string s = 
  @"[with0]
  [ with0 ]
  [sometext with0 sometext]
  [sometext with0]
  [with0 sometext]


  with1
  ] with1
  hello with1
  hello with1 world
  hello [ world] with1 hello
  hello [ world] with1 hello [world]";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\[[^][]*\]|(?<KEYWORD>\bwith\d\b)");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  if (m.Groups["KEYWORD"].Success)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoting this, nice one Alan. :) Believe it or not, I've only seen 3 other questions on SO that use this technique, despite looking at many similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into both negative look-behinds and negative look-aheads, this will help you match your data without consuming the brackets.