# Need help splitting a string in java

Tags: java, split

I'm using java and have the following string I'm trying to split into tokens.

```
FirstName M LastName (email domain.com)
```

which should end up looking like this

```
FirstName
M
LastName
(email domain.com)
```

I was using **split("\s");** which worked great until I introduced email. Now it splits the email on the space which should be left intact.

I do not know how to split all white space with the exception of the space between the braces.

I'd like to point out that the data may come in any order and may or may not be there.

Comment: should probably look up Pattern and regex in general

Comment: What end result are you trying to achieve? Please be more specific by "data may come in any order and may or may not be there".  Please tag "homework" if relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005784/regex-to-match-a-string-not-sorrounded-by-brackets , this should get you started, different language though, but you can adapt it :)

Comment: @bkail I posted my end result, What I mean with the data being in any order is it could be "m (email domain.com) lastName" or "firstName lastName (email domain.com) m".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but it's one possible way. The regex `"\\s(?!\\S*\\))"` may do what you want.

This regex will match any space character (the `\\s`) which is not followed (negative lookahead; the `(?!)` group) by some number of non-space characters and a ")" (the `\\S\\)`). This will work for a lot of input but breaks down if there are any other instances of ")" in the given string. For example, using that to split this string will not work: "FirstName M) LastName (email domain.com)". It would split into these strings:

```
FirstName M)
LastName
(email domain.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if the first few characters don't support parentheses, you could split on ( first.
And then split the first string after trimming it on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression is the way to go.  This is a simplistic version, but it does work.  Something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RESample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toSplit = "FirstName M LastName (email domain.com)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+)\\s*([^\\s]+)\\s*([^\\s]+)\\s*(.*)");

        Matcher result = pattern.matcher(toSplit);
        if ( result.matches() )
        {
            String firstName = result.group(1);
            System.out.println("First: " + firstName);
            String mName = result.group(2);
            System.out.println("Middle: " + mName);
            String lastName = result.group(3);
            System.out.println("Last: " + lastName);
            String email = result.group(4);
            System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No matches");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for other orderings (e.g. "firstName lastName (email domain.com) m" which is part of the requirements.

Comment: Yes this is text being split from a keyword field, so the order of the fields will very.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split("\\s+", 2)`. This will limit number of array elements

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic.

Comment: @George that is because that code limits it to 2 elements. You want 4 elements, so change the `split("\\s+", 2)` to `split("\\s+", 4)`. Also, note the `+` after `\\s`. This way, you won't get blank array elements if extra whitespace is inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do following piece of code :

```
String[] splits = message.split("(");
String[] name = splits[0].split("\s");
for( String str : name)
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("(" + splits[1]);
```

Comment: Note, this does not work. `split` uses regex, so `(` looks like a [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) so an exception is thrown. Instead, you need to escape it; replace `message.split("(");` with `message.split("\\(");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
final String[] splits = message.split("(?<!email) ");
```

It uses a negative lookbehind. That is, split on space that is not preceded by "email".