# String replace regex take tokens only outside []

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

I am trying to replace all the spaces in string with '+'. But it should ignore ignore the spaces inside the []. Do anyone know how to do this using regular expression.

Example:

```
latitude[0 TO *] longitude[10 TO *]
```

should be replaced as

```
latitude[0 TO *]+longitude[10 TO *]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace ("global" flag enabled)

```
\s(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))
```

with

```
+
```

Explanation

```
\s          # white-space (use an actual space if you want)
(?=         # but only when followed by (i.e. look-ahead)...
  [^\]]*    #   ...anything but a "]"
  (?:       #   non-apturing group ("either of")
    \[      #     "["
    |       #     or
    $       #     the end of the string
  )         #   end non-capturing group
)           # end look-ahead
```

This matches any space that is not inside a square bracket, under the assumption that there are no incorrectly opened/closed square brackets in the string and that square brackets are never nested.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a machine state instead of a regex. This way, you can stop replacing whitespaces when you're "inside" the []. If you go with a regex, you will likely need to use a lookahead, making it more complicate. There is a similar example here:
[Replace whitespace outside quotes using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111749/replace-whitespace-outside-quotes-using-regular-expression)