# How can I parse *.cat file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to parse [this](http://pastie.org/7461356) file. Here is a sample fragment.

```
    '13138' => { 'REFERENCE' => '13138', 'NAME' => 'DRAPER Five 125mm Medium Grade Aluminium Oxide Sanding Discs', 'PRICE' => 108, 'MIN_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 1, 'MAX_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 0, 'OUT_OF_STOCK' => 0, 'DATE_PROMPT' => '', 'OTHER_INFO_PROMPT' => '', 'PRICING_MODEL' => 0, 'TAX_1' => '101=2000.00=0=', 'OPAQUE_SHIPPING_DATA' => '0.054', 'ALT_WEIGHT' => '', 'SHIP_SEPARATELY' => 0, 'SHIP_CATEGORY' => '', 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'SHIP_QUANTITY' => 1, 'COST_PRICE' => 0, 'EXCLUDE_FROM_SHIP' => 0, 'ASSEMBLY_PRODUCT' => 0, 'STOCK_AISLE' => '', 'STOCK_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_SUB_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_BIN' => '', 'BARCODE' => '', 'REPORT_DESC' => '', 'PRICES' => {
    1 => [
        [0,108],
    ],
},
    'CUSTOMVARS' => 
        {
        },
'NO_ORDERLINE' => 0, 'AUTOSHIP' => 0, 'PRODUCT_GROUP' => -1, 'THUMBNAIL' => '', 'IMAGE' => '13138_694.jpg', 'ALSOBOUGHT' => [], 'RELATED' => [],  }, 
    '13139' => { 'REFERENCE' => '13139', 'NAME' => 'DRAPER Five 125mm Coarse Grade Aluminium Oxide Sanding Discs', 'PRICE' => 96, 'MIN_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 1, 'MAX_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 0, 'OUT_OF_STOCK' => 0, 'DATE_PROMPT' => '', 'OTHER_INFO_PROMPT' => '', 'PRICING_MODEL' => 0, 'TAX_1' => '101=2000.00=0=', 'OPAQUE_SHIPPING_DATA' => '0.066', 'ALT_WEIGHT' => '', 'SHIP_SEPARATELY' => 0, 'SHIP_CATEGORY' => '', 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'SHIP_QUANTITY' => 1, 'COST_PRICE' => 0, 'EXCLUDE_FROM_SHIP' => 0, 'ASSEMBLY_PRODUCT' => 0, 'STOCK_AISLE' => '', 'STOCK_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_SUB_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_BIN' => '', 'BARCODE' => '', 'REPORT_DESC' => '', 'PRICES' => {
    1 => [
        [0,96],
    ],
},
    'CUSTOMVARS' => 
        {
        },
'NO_ORDERLINE' => 0, 'AUTOSHIP' => 0, 'PRODUCT_GROUP' => -1, 'THUMBNAIL' => '', 'IMAGE' => '13139_694.jpg', 'ALSOBOUGHT' => [], 'RELATED' => [],  }, 
    '13140' => { 'REFERENCE' => '13140', 'NAME' => 'DRAPER Five Extra Coarse Grade Aluminium Oxide Sanding Discs', 'PRICE' => 96, 'MIN_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 1, 'MAX_QUANTITY_ORDERABLE' => 0, 'OUT_OF_STOCK' => 0, 'DATE_PROMPT' => '', 'OTHER_INFO_PROMPT' => '', 'PRICING_MODEL' => 0, 'TAX_1' => '101=2000.00=0=', 'OPAQUE_SHIPPING_DATA' => '0.055', 'ALT_WEIGHT' => '', 'SHIP_SEPARATELY' => 0, 'SHIP_CATEGORY' => '', 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT' => 0, 'HAND_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE' => 0, 'SHIP_QUANTITY' => 1, 'COST_PRICE' => 0, 'EXCLUDE_FROM_SHIP' => 0, 'ASSEMBLY_PRODUCT' => 0, 'STOCK_AISLE' => '', 'STOCK_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_SUB_RACK' => '', 'STOCK_BIN' => '', 'BARCODE' => '', 'REPORT_DESC' => '', 'PRICES' => {
    1 => [
        [0,96],
    ],
},
    'CUSTOMVARS' => 
        {
        },
'NO_ORDERLINE' => 0, 'AUTOSHIP' => 0, 'PRODUCT_GROUP' => -1, 'THUMBNAIL' => '', 'IMAGE' => '13140_694ii.jpg', 'ALSOBOUGHT' => [], 'RELATED' => [],  },
```

Here it contains 3 items. They starts with string like `'13138' => { 'REFERENCE'`. and end before same type of string. How can I split those parts?

I tried `re.search(r"{ 'REFERENCE'.*?(?={ 'REFERENCE')", catstr)`. But it does not match.

Comment: Are these ruby hashes?

Comment: @limelights not sure. Its found on a website created by `Actinic`.  They declare `<Actinic:SECTION BLOB='A000253.cat'/>` in html and `A000253.cat` is the file I want to parse. [Sample](http://pastie.org/7461356).

Comment: Also, maybe you'd want to correct the `[this][1]` markup to point to an actual file. If you're not sure about the markup, you can use the "link" button on the top of the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just replace `=>` with `:`:

```
    'CUSTOMVARS' :
        {
        },
'NO_ORDERLINE' : 0, 'AUTOSHIP' : 0, 'PRODUCT_GROUP' : -1, ...
```

And evaluate it using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). It evaluates only literals, not executable code, so sanitizing is not necessary (except maybe guards for excessively large inputs):

> ```
> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
> ```
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression.
>   The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from
>   untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

**EDIT: A working example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-

import urllib2
import ast
import re
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

pp = PrettyPrinter()
resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://pastie.org/pastes/7461356/download")
content = resp.read()
content = re.search(r"\s+=\s+({(?:.|\n)+});", content).group(1)
# Fix following line to handle => inside strings, if needed
content = re.sub(r"=>", r":", content) 
parsed = ast.literal_eval(content)
pp.pprint(parsed)
```

For information about replacing `=>` only outside strings, please see
this answer:

- [Replace whitespace outside quotes using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111749/replace-whitespace-outside-quotes-using-regular-expression)

**EDIT**

The given file contains other tokens apart from the hash itself. The regexp in
`re.search` above strips the superfluous tokens:

```
\s+=\s+      # This marks the = before the start of the hash
({           # Capture the first {
  (?:.|\n)+  # This matches all characters.
             # The (?: is to prevent capture-inside-capture
})           # Capture the last }
;            # This is not captured
```

Comment: I wouldn't even mention `eval` in a case like this ;)

Comment: @mata thanks for the heads-up, `literal_eval` is clearly superior in this case. Removed mention of `eval`.

Comment: The only thing one would have to worry about is the presence of `=>` in one of the name strings somewhere, which would be changed incorrectly by this method unless done very carefully.

Comment: I copy pasted the content and tried it. But didn't work. But when I downloaded and used raw content using urllib2 it did work. Thanks for ab working example