# replaceAll boundaries and exceptions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use `replaceAll` to eliminate all of the whitespace in a string with the exception of two areas.

If my string is

```
AB CD #E     F# #GH   I# JK L   M
```

then I want it to output as

```
ABCD#E     F##GH   I#IJKLM
```

Currently, it is outputting `ABCD#EF##GH#IJKLM` without discriminating the `#` characters. Is there a way to do that with regular expressions on replaceAll?

```
String s1 = "AB CD #E     F# #GH   I# JK L   M";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: When you say `AB CD #E F# #GH# IJKL M` shall result in `ABCD#E F##GH#IJKLM`, can you explain the logic behind this ?

Comment: It may also help to provide an example with more whitespace in more places... `" A B C # D E # F G # H I J "`

Comment: I want to able to parse any user input so that all of the white space outside of the '#' is eliminated to make it easier for me. Additionally, I'm going to take the two strings between the '#' and put those in my data structure later.

Comment: So in other words, we should think of `#` as like quotes, where there is an opening and closing `#`, and any whitespace in between should be preserved?

Comment: How do you define "outside of the '#'"?  If you have `x#y#z#a#b#c`, what constitutes as "outside" and what constitutes as "inside"?

Comment: Sorry about all the edits, just trying to help - Hope I'm interpreting your intent correctly.  Whitespace is not preserved in-line, so it works better if you format as code with indenting four spaces.

Comment: @atk Tried to add more whitespaces to my example string in the description, but it prints out with only one space.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace whitespace outside quotes using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111749/replace-whitespace-outside-quotes-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not good at regular expressions. I will use a loop for this.

```
String s1 = "AB CD #E     F# #GH   I# JK L   M";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean keepSpace = false;
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
    char c = s1.charAt(i);
    if(keepSpace || c != ' ')
        sb.append(c);
    if(c == '#')
        keepSpace = !keepSpace;
}
s1 = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: +1 This is a much better approach than regex for this situation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm forcing the use of regex, but I wanted to practice with it. Although this is far more elegant than what I was planning. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for this positive lookahead based regex in `replaceAll`:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\s+(?=(?:(?:[^#]*#){2})*[^#]*$)", "");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/nFQhVt

**Explanation:** This regex is using a positive lookahead that basically is matching 0 or more occurrences of a pair of some text until a hash (#) is found i.e. `([^#]*"){2}` on the right hand side (RHS) of every match of a space.

Which in simple term means replace a space only if it is outside pair of hash signs, since all the matches inside hash will have odd number of `[^#]*#` matches on RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+(?=(?:[^#]*#[^#]*#)*[^#]*$)", "");
```

It will only replace spaces when there are an even number of `#` ahead in the string.
And it is therefore far from foolproof, but it may be good enough.
You could always test the string first to make sure it contains an even number of `#`.